# Cannot find module tooltip-basic

Tags: angular, module, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to get the ng-bootstrap tooltips working (or any of their widgets really) with my Angular 7 app.

While ng-bootstrap seems to have installed ok, Nothing happens when I use the tooltip like this =

```
<button (click)="Search();" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on left">Search</button>
```

This all comes from their stackblitz example... 
https://stackblitz.com/angular/kdrndneoong?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your app module? Where is your tooltip-baisc component?

Comment: oh... man  i read that stack blitz thing all wrong.  That NgbdTooltipBasic is their example component.  So I don't need that at all.  such a mixup :P 

But even still, i can't get the tooltip to work.  Nothing shows up.  

I will amend my question...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after trying a few things, it seems that ng-bootstrap will only work if I have it in the direct module I am working in.  In this case entity.module.ts

I had previously had it in app.module.ts thinking that was a global all and would flow into all other subsequent modules.  It does not appear my app works that way.  But I am not sure why...

Either way, the solution was to move the

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

to my entity.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add extensions for your imports?

For example:

```
import { NgbdTooltipBasic } from './tooltip-basic.js';
```

instead of

```
import { NgbdTooltipBasic } from './tooltip-basic';
```